# Export html from database to Excel including formatting with python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to write a code to export a database with mutliple text/number/date/html columns to Excel.

There are exactly 4 columns containg html
The only part that doesn't work is **conversion html to Excel**

**first part** - extraction of the data from database and creation of list with data rows as dict.

```
def export_excel_background(data, type, delimiter, report_type, data_type):
    """export data"""
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    import os
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import xlsxwriter

    dicts = []
    all_records = []#hold found rows
    i = 0
    total_progress = len(data)

  

    for x in data:#iterate the list
        
        dict_search = {}#dict for search
        if data_type != 'list': #data type search iterator
          dict_search['application_code'] = x['application_code']
        else:#list
          dict_search['application_code'] = x
  
        progress = (i / total_progress) * 100
        anvil.server.task_state['progress'] = int(progress)  # Update progress
        i += 1

        for r in app_tables.assay_databank.search(**dict_search):#search database
          matrix = r['matrix']#it's a list
          matrix_text = ', '.join(matrix) if matrix else ''
          new_item = {'Assay name long': r['name_long'], 'Assay name short': r['name_short'], 'Application code': r['application_code'],
                  'Matrix': matrix_text, 'Indication': r['indication'], 'Difficulty level': r['difficulty_level'],
                  'Dilution': r['dilution'], 'Spiking': r['spiking'], 'Storage temp.': r['storage_temperature'],
                  'Method of comparison': r['method_of_comparison'], 'Additional information': r['additional_information'],
                  'Object Status': r['object_status'],
                  'Created by': r['created_by']['email'], 'Creation date': r['creation_date'].strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'),
                  'Updated by': r['updated_by']['email'], 'Updated date': r['updated_date'].strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')}
          dicts.append(new_item)
```

***Keys with html:***

- 'Method of comparison'
- 'Dilution'
- 'Spiking'
- 'Additional information'

**What the 2nd part do:**

- defines the available formats and their combinations.
- iterate rows of the above mentioned columns tag by tag and converts scraps of text into a formated excel cells.
- but... the possible combinations of formats are making it unfuctionable...

It's not challenging if you have only single combinations like **text** or *text*. The real problem starts when you combine them... ***text***. Like italic + bold, bold + italic + underlined + numbered etc. In that case looping tag by tag won't let me to apply the right formats to the text.

**Is there some easier way to convert html into formatted excel?**

some example of html that I was trying to convert:
**example 1:** `<ol><li>one</li><li>two</li></ol><p><a href=\"google.com\" target=\"_blank\">link</a></p>`
"

1. one
2. two

<a href="google.com" target="_blank">link

"

**example 2:** `<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul>`
"

- a
- b
- c

"

**example 3:** `<p><strong>bold</strong></p><p><em>italic</em></p><p><u>underlined</u></p><p>normal</p><p><strong><em><u>combined</u></em></strong></p><p><br></p>`
"

**bold**

*italic*

underlined

normal

***combined***

"

**example 4:** `<h1>header1</h1><h2>header2</h2><h3>header3</h3>`
"

## header1

### header2

#### header3

"

**2nd part of code** - conversion html to Excel and saving the new file in database for user to download it.

```
    #first part of code...

    # Create the DataFrame
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts)
    

    # Create an Excel writer with xlsxwriter engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df2.to_excel(writer, index=True, index_label='Index')
    
    # Access the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('Sheet1')  # Get the correct worksheet by name
    
    # Define the required formats
    bold_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    italic_format = workbook.add_format({'italic': True})
    underline_format = workbook.add_format({'underline': True})
    combined_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True, 'underline': True})
    bold_underline_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'underline': True})
    bold_italic_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})
    underline_italic_format = workbook.add_format({'underline': True, 'italic': True})
    link_format = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'blue', 'underline': True})
    ordered_list_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0. ', 'indent': 1})
    bullet_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '•', 'indent': 1})
    h1_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_size': 14})
    h2_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_size': 12})
    h3_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_size': 10})
    
    # Write the header row separately to avoid overwriting it
    worksheet.write_row(0, 1, df2.columns, bold_format)
    
    # Write the index column separately
    worksheet.write_column(1, 0, df2.index)
    
    # Iterate over the columns to apply formatting
    for col_num, column_name in enumerate(df2.columns):
            if column_name in ['Additional information', 'Method of comparison', 'Spiking', 'Dilution']:
                print(column_name)
                # Apply HTML formatting for specific columns
                for row, cell_value in enumerate(df2[column_name]):
                    if not pd.isnull(cell_value):
                        # Parse the HTML content
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(cell_value, 'html.parser')
    
                    # Create a list to store the formatted parts of the cell value
                    formatted_parts = []
        
                    previous_text = ''
                    current_formats = set()
                    combined_text = ''
                    
                    for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=True):
                        if tag.name == 'p' or tag.name == 'br':
                            # Handle line breaks with newlines
                            formatted_parts.append('\n')
                        elif tag.name == 'a':
                            # Handle links by extracting the URL
                            link_url = tag.get('href', '')
                            formatted_parts.extend([link_format, link_url, tag.text])
                        elif tag.name == 'ol':
                            # Handle ordered list
                            formatted_parts.append(ordered_list_format)
                            formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'ul':
                            # Handle unordered list
                            formatted_parts.append(bullet_format)
                            formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'strong':
                            # Handle bold text
                            current_formats.add('strong')
                            if previous_text == tag.text and 'em' in current_formats and 'u' in current_formats:
                                # Apply the combined format to the entire text
                                combined_text = tag.text
                            elif 'u' in current_formats:
                                formatted_parts.append(bold_italic_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                            else:
                                formatted_parts.append(bold_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'em':
                            # Handle italic text
                            current_formats.add('em')
                            if previous_text == tag.text and 'strong' in current_formats and 'u' in current_formats:
                                # Apply the combined format to the entire text
                                combined_text = tag.text
                            elif 'u' in current_formats:
                                formatted_parts.append(bold_italic_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                            else:
                                formatted_parts.append(italic_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'u':
                            # Handle underlined text
                            current_formats.add('u')
                            if previous_text == tag.text and 'strong' in current_formats and 'em' in current_formats:
                                # Apply the combined format to the entire text
                                combined_text = tag.text
                            elif 'strong' in current_formats or 'em' in current_formats:
                                formatted_parts.append(bold_italic_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                            else:
                                formatted_parts.append(underline_format)
                                formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'h1':
                            # Handle header 1
                            formatted_parts.append(h1_format)
                            formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'h2':
                            # Handle header 2
                            formatted_parts.append(h2_format)
                            formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                        elif tag.name == 'h3':
                            # Handle header 3
                            formatted_parts.append(h3_format)
                            formatted_parts.append(tag.text)
                          
                        previous_text = tag.text

                    if combined_text:
                        formatted_parts.append(combined_format)
                        formatted_parts.append(combined_text)
                    elif 'u' in current_formats:
                        formatted_parts.append(underline_format)
                        formatted_parts.append(previous_text)
                    # Write the formatted value to the cell using write_rich_string()
                    col_index = col_num + 1
                    row_index = row + 1
                    text = worksheet.write_rich_string(row_index, col_index, *formatted_parts)
            else:
                # For columns without HTML formatting, write the values as plain text
                worksheet.write_column(1, col_num + 1, df2[column_name])
    
        # Close the Excel writer
        writer.save()
  
        content = io.BytesIO()
        now = datetime.now()
    
        if type == 'excel':
            file_name = now.strftime(f"%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S-Assays.xlsx")
            with open('pandas_simple.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
                content.write(file.read())
            media = anvil.BlobMedia(content=content.getvalue(), name=file_name, content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
        elif type == 'CSV':
            file_name = now.strftime(f"%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S-Assays.csv")
            if delimiter == 'semicolon':
                df2.to_csv(content, index=True, sep=';', index_label='Index')
            elif delimiter == 'comma':
                df2.to_csv(content, index=True, sep=',', index_label='Index')
            elif delimiter == 'vertical bar':
                df2.to_csv(content, index=True, sep='|', index_label='Index')
            media = anvil.BlobMedia(content=content.getvalue(), name=file_name, content_type="text/csv")
    
        id = app_tables.export_media_transfer.add_row(object=media, date=datetime.now()).get_id()
        return id
```